# Adding Security to .Netcore 2.1 Api

Tags: security, .net-core, jwt, owin

I have a .netcore 2.1 API which will be invoked by a curl script from Mac's.

The curl script is invoked at the login of the Mac.

I want to add security to the API , so that the API cannot be accessed by everyone on the network to update the database.

I am new to security kind of thing so not sure how to proceed with this.

I have been reading about OWIN/JWT etc.

I also read about JWT which registeres user and authenticates based on the password stored in database.

But what I want is to authenticate the computers which can access the database, as it will not be used by the individuals but will be called from each computer when its turned on.

Is this possible? If not what should be my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Api Key

This is a weak way of doing it, but generate an Api Key that you can pass as a header to curl.  Requests that don't have the header, don't get access.  e.g. pass the header:

```
curl -H "X-Api-Key: {{key}}" https://foo
```

Then create a middleware class that checks the header:

```
... (pseudo code for middleware) ...
if (Request.Headers["X-Api-Key"] == {{key}}) {
  return next();  // key is good keep going
} else {
  return;  // key isn't valid.
}
...
```

### JWT

Have the server generate a unique identifier for each client.  The identifier for should be something that isn’t easily guessable, e.g. a unique id plus some secure random material.  When you install the scripts on the client, distribute this identifier with it.  Not sure how you’re planning on distributing the scripts, so I can’t comment on that here.

Once this information is installed on the client, the scripts would make a call to the server to generate a JWT.  The token should include an expiration date/time and ideally make use of jti to prevent replay attacks.

This blog provides a good overview of using JWT, https://pioneercode.com/post/authentication-in-an-asp-dot-net-core-api-part-3-json-web-token.

In the authenticate method where you generate the token, instead of checking against the password, you would check against your client keys database — I’d strongly advise using good security discipline and not store the actual data, but instead salted and hashed data on the server — treat these keys like passwords!!  When you create the tokens, make sure you set an expiration and if you want to go one step further, use jti to prevent replay attacks.

Return the new token to your script, and then make your original API request passing the bearer token:

```
curl -H “Authorization: {{token}}” https://foo/api/bar
```

Make sure this is all done over via HTTPS as well.

### SSL/TLS Mutual Authentication

Another way to handle this (more complicated, but more secure) is using SSL/TLS mutual authentication.  I’ve not tried setting this up in using .NET Core, but you can frontend your .NET process using Nginx which can be configured for mutual auth.  Have a look at https://blog.codeship.com/how-to-set-up-mutual-tls-authentication/.

In this approach, you’d create your own root CA, generate a certificate for each of your clients, and figure out a way to install the certificate on the client.  Make sure you set the permissions of the client certificate file to be user read only (chmod 400 client-cert.pem) and then use the --cert/--key arguments.

In this scenario you’ll still need to worry about replacing certificates prior to their expiration.

Comment: Hi Jason,Thank you for your reply. After reading your comment and reading few articles on JWT I have decided to go for JWT. How do I use curl to create the token an then pass it to the next curl to post my value? I am new to curl so not familiar with it to great extend.

Comment: JWT sounds like a good way to go.  As for getting the token, your first curl request will be to your authentication service.  Your second request would be your regular service.  A quick way would be for the first request to just respond with the encoded token as "text/plain" instead of a JSON response.  

A short one-line might be:

`curl -H 'Authorization: \`curl -s https://foo/getmejwt -X POST -d machine secret.json\`' -X POST https://bar/yourservice`

Note, I haven't tried this exact command, but the idea is backtick the call to get the JWT and feed it into the `Authorization` header.

Comment: I tried JWT and it worked. But we decided not to go with it because , it is the Macs which call the api through curl and there is no user interaction(so i had to go for a key rather than a username password kind of scenario). So we could not find a reason to go with it. But this answer suits where api is accessed by users.

Comment: Glad you found a solution!